# Compile error with catchfilebetweentags

Tags: errors, catchfile

I tried to test the package `catchfilebetweentags` with the following minimal example, but get a compile error. What's wrong here and how to fix it?

Contents of `catch_main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\CatchFBT@Fin@l}{\endlinechar\m@ne}{}
  {}{\typeout{Unsuccessful patch!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ExecuteMetaData[inputfile]{mytag1}

\ExecuteMetaData[inputfile]{mytag1}


\ExecuteMetaData[inputfile]{mytag2}

\end{document}
```

Contents of `inputfile.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}%

\begin{document}
Some text.
%<*mytag1>
This is the text for mytag1.
% </mytag1>

%<*mytag2>
This is the other text for mytag2.
% </mytag2>


\end{document}
```

Compiler messages:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `catch_main' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" catch_main.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(./catch_main.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(./catch_main.aux) (./inputfile.tex)
Runaway text?
 This is the text for mytag1. \par This is the other text for mytag2.\ETC.
./catch_main.tex:11: File ended while scanning text of \CatchFBT@tok.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11 \ExecuteMetaData[inputfile]{mytag1}

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./catch_main.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on catch_main.pdf (1 page, 13823 bytes).
Transcript written on catch_main.log.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Sat Jul 23 16:50:02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in `inputfile.tex`. The end tag should not contain a space:

`% </mytag1>` ⇒ `%</mytag1>`

Corrected version of `inputfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\begin{document}
Some text.
%<*mytag1>
This is the text for mytag1.
%</mytag1>

%<*mytag2>
This is the other text for mytag2.
%</mytag2>


\end{document}
```